# Making an HTTP request in Pharo and getting the response headers

Tags: http, smalltalk, squeak, pharo

how can I make an HTTP request and get both the response content and the response headers?

Answer (score 7):

Or using the new [Zinc framework](http://zn.stfx.eu/zn/index.html), something like:

```
| response content headers |

response := ZnClient new 
    url: 'http://stackoverflow.com';
    get;
    response.

content := response contents.
headers := response headers.
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest is if you load `WebClient` from http://www.squeaksource.com/WebClient.

Comment: WebClient has actual, useful documentation too!

Answer (score 1):

To install WebClient:

```
(Installer ss project: 'WebClient')
  install: 'WebClient-Core'
```

and then

```
response := WebClient httpGet: 'http://www.google.com/'.
headers := response headers. "An OrderedCollection of headername -> headervalue"
body := response content.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to do something more with them, the seaside one-click image for [pharo](http://www.seaside.st/distributions/Seaside-3.0rc.app.zip) or [squeak](http://ftp.squeak.org/various_images/seaside/Squeak4.1/Seaside3.0-All-in-One.zip)